# Can we show that the supremum of the following functional over the unit sphere in $C^0[0,1]$ is $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the following functional (Luenberger ''Optimization by Vector Space Methods", p40) defined on $C^0[0,1]$:

$$f(x)=\int_0^{1/2}x(t)dt-\int_{1/2}^1x(t)dt$$

We are interested in its supremum over the unit sphere $S(0,1)\doteq \big\{x\in C^0[0,1]: ||x||=1\big\}$. Here the norm is the usual one for $C^0[0,1]$, i.e. $||x||\doteq \sup_{0\leq t \leq 1}|x(t)|$.

I can show that $|f(x)| \leq ||x||$. Hence, an upper bound of $f(x)$ over the unit sphere is $1$. Luenberger claims that the supremum is also $1$. I just wonder how to prove it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $x=1$ on $[0,1/2),$ $x=-1$ on $(1/2,1],$ then $f(x)=1.$ That's not possible of course, but you can get close to it.

Comment: Thank you @zhw for your prompt reply. Did you mean that we can construct continuous approximations that approach to the function you described?

Comment: Compute $f$ of the function whose graph is the line joining $(0,-1), ({1 \over 2}-{1 \over n}, -1), ({1 \over 2}+{1 \over n}, 1), (1,1)$. Let $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @camio Yes, that was what I meant.